# C Why does 2 pointers pointing to the same variable print only if there is no asterisk(*)

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Quick summary: In our activity, we were supposed to declare 3 variables (x, y, and z) and 4 pointer variables (p1, p2, p3, and p4). Two of those pointer variables (p3 and p4) should point to the same variable (z).

in this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/

it said:

```
// C program to demonstrate use of * for pointers in C 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    // A normal integer variable 
    int Var = 10; 

    // A pointer variable that holds the address of var. 
    int *ptr = &Var; 

    // This line prints value at address stored in ptr. 
    // Value stored is value of variable "var" 
    printf("Value of Var = %d\n", *ptr); 

    // The output of this line may be different in different 
    // runs even on same machine. 
    printf("Address of Var = %p\n", ptr);
```

So I did my code:

```
int main () {

    int x = 10;
        int *p1= &x;

    float y = 12.5;
        float *p2 = &y;
```

Now is for the p3 and p4 pointer variables.
I found this thread: [Can two pointer variables point to the same memory Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959416/can-two-pointer-variables-point-to-the-same-memory-address?rq=1)

which said in the answer:
**"Yes, two-pointer variables can point to the same object:
Pointers are variables whose value is the address of a C object, or the null pointer.
multiple pointers can point to the same object:"**

```
char *p, *q;
p = q = "a";
```

and did that as well:

```
int main () {

    int x = 10;
        int *p1= &x;

    float y = 12.5;
        float *p2 = &y;

    char z = 'G';
        char *p3, *p4;
        p3 = p4 = &z;
```

My confusion now is when printing p3 and p4:

```
int main () {

    int x = 10;
        int *p1= &x;

    float y = 12.5;
        float *p2 = &y;

    char z = 'G';
        char *p3, *p4;
        p3 = p4 = &z;

    printf("%d  %.2f %s %s", *p1, *p2, p3, p4);
```

**Why in the line printf("%d  %.2f %s %s", *p1, *p2, p3, p4); it only print p3 and p4 only if they don't have the asterisk??**

Comment: `p3` and `p4` are pointers to a **single-character literal** not a character at the beginning of a *nul-terminated* string. Use `"%c"` to output them and derefernce `*p3, *p4` in `printf("%d  %.2f %c %c", *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4);` A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102)

Comment: David’s comment should be an answer.

Comment: `p3` is not a string: it points to a single char, not to a sequence of chars `'\0'` terminated.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh I see, so that's why... thanks!

Comment: Yep, you can also just use `putchar(*p3)` or `putchar(*p4)` to output the single characters separately without relying on the `printf` *format-string* and the `"%c"` *conversion-specifiers*. (`"%s"` expects a pointer to the first character in a *nul-terminated* string as the argument, `"%c"` expects an actual characters as the argument)  Take a look at the links above -- they are for different problems, but the discussions in the answers provide pointer basics. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the problem with `p3` and `p4`? ... Well, they don't point to what you are using them as...

`p3` and `p4` are pointers to a **single-character literal** not a character at the beginning of a *nul-terminated* string. Use `"%c"` to output them and derefernce `*p3, *p4` in `printf("%d  %.2f %c %c", *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4);`

Answer (score 0):

> "*Why in the line `printf("%d %.2f %s %s", *p1, *p2, p3, p4);` it only print p3 and p4 only if they don't have the asterisk??*"

First of all, The `%s` conversion specifier, as opposed to `%c`, expects an argument of type `char *`, not `char`.

If you would use `*p3` and/or `*p4` there would be a type mismatch - `char` vs. `char*`.

---

Your main issue:

`p3` and `p4` point to `z` which is just a single `char` object, not an array which contains a string. To use `%s` with a pointer to a single character, which is not the null character, invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

If you want to print the character hold in `z` by the pointers `p3` and `p4`, use the `%c` format specifier to print a single character and precede each pointer argument by the asterisk operator `*` to dereference the pointers:

```
printf("%d %.2f %c %c", *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's totally irrelevant if you assign one or more pointers to the same variable, don't let it confuse you. You can just as well remove `p4` from your code and it would work the same (print `p3` without the asterisk.

When you declare `char*` it is considered a `char array`. So, when you are printing `p1` and `p2`, which are `int` and `float` respectively (numeric types), you need to dereference your pointer, and when printing an array, there is no need to dereference. For further reading I would recommend [going here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155012/why-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-to-string-char-array-returns-the-whole-string).

Comment: Pointers aren’t arrays.

Comment: @CarlNorum Edited it as soon as I posted it, it was a stupid formulation of a sentence.

Comment: That was what our activity said: "Activity 11: Declare 3 variables x, y, and z as integer, float, and character with initial values 10, 12.5, and ‘G’ respectively. Also, declare 4 pointer variables p1, p2, p3, and p4 so that p1 points to x, p2 points to y, p3, and p4 point to z. "

Comment: @SethJustinValenciano I didn't mean you should remove `p4`, I meant that the fact that you have two pointers both pointing to `z` doesn't influence the fact that you need/don't need asterisk.